# Can we consider the recent question about syncing to Android on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

I don't think this question is off-topic:

- [Apple cloud replacement?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181782/apple-cloud-replacement)

But it seems like a lot of other people do, and it looks like it may be closed soon.

In that question, the OP is asking if you can work on documents, check and write email, use instant messaging, and so forth, all on Ubuntu ...and sync the relevant information (e.g., newest versions of documents, contact lists) with an Android phone.

While I'm not sure the current answer is sufficiently Ubuntu-specific, and I can see why people may think of this as an Android question rather than an Ubuntu question, I think this is **fundamentally a question about what you can do with Ubuntu, and how to do it**.

I think it should be possible to explain how to use each of Ubuntu's several main productivity applications, syncing data with an Android phone. A very general answer that explains that--with some screenshots for good measure, and perhaps links to relevant Android documentation or questions on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), would probably answer the question quite well. (I don't have any Android devices; otherwise, I'd be writing such an answer right now, rather than writing this meta question.)

So I don't think that question should be closed. On the other hand, if we really can't give an Ubuntu-specific answer to it, then it probably should be closed. What do you all think? Is a good, on-topic answer that addresses the specifics of Ubuntu possible? Does anyone feel prepared and willing to write such an answer?

Comment: It got closed. *shrug* And I had such a nice answer drafted for it too... :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah. It's not just about syncing Android - it's about syncing Android *with Ubuntu*.

I'll push an edit to make that clearer.